# iOS : gitlab-runner stuck on CI

Tags: ios, xcode, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I am working on Gitlab CI, but getting some issue relate to test run, as below command is working on terminal and given perfectly test result but somehow its now run on gitlab CI.

below is my **.gitlab-ci.yml**

```
stages:
  - build

build_project:
  stage: build
  script:
    - xcodebuild clean -workspace "First Container.xcworkspace" -scheme "First Container" | xcpretty
    - xcodebuild test -workspace "First Container.xcworkspace" -scheme "First Container" -destination 'platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPhone 8 Plus,OS=11.3' | xcpretty
  tags:
    - ios_11-3
    - xcode_9-3
    - osx_10-13-4
```

below command work on my terminal:

```
   $ xcodebuild test -workspace "First Container.xcworkspace" -scheme "First Container" -destination 'platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPhone 8 Plus,OS=11.3' | xcpretty
```

but it stuck when I run on CI, my gitlab-runner not launch iPhone simulator and run the  test, build is working

[image]

Comment: try a lower iOS version for the simulator. say iOS `9.x`.

Comment: How were you able to see the logs of the runner?

Answer (score 2):

Do not use `sudo` when you do `gitlab-runner register` and later `gitlab-runner start`. That way it will run in *user-mode* (as opposed to *system-mode*). If you've already used `sudo`, remove the runner (from GitLab Web UI) and register again.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a little late, but it's better than nothing at all.

As @acastano and @Nikolay have said, make sure your registration for the gitlab-runner was correct. My mistake was, as a macOS-User I followed the Linux instead of the macOS-Registration. Otherwise remove the gitlab-runner from GitLab.com `Settings » CI / CD » Runners » Remove Runner` and register again.

After that change your `.gitlab-ci.yml` as follow:

```
stages:
- build

variables:
  LC_ALL: "en_US.UTF-8"

build_project:
  stage: build
  script:
    - xcodebuild clean -project testProject.xcodeproj -scheme testProject+ | xcpretty
    - xcodebuild test -project testProject.xcodeproj -scheme testProject+ -destination 'platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPhone X,OS=12.1' | xcpretty -s
```

The `variables: LC_ALL: "en_US.UTF-8"` is important, otherwise the gitlab-runner displays an error. Now start the gitlab-runner:

```
gitlab-runner start
gitlab-runner install
gitlab-runner run
```

Make sure you **never** use `sudo`. Finally check your Gitlab CI:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This was happening to me. The reason was because I was running the runner in system mode.

I changed to use mode and it worked after changing the permissions in the folders needed.

Comment: How you change the mode...?

Comment: system mode sudo gitlab-runner run

Comment: use-mode gitlab-runner run

Comment: run gitlab-runner list to check that the runner is there

Comment: I have already tired that one, but simulator not launchd and stuck over there... have you simulator launch ???

Comment: I left the simulator open I have no steps to open the simulator